# Concatenate the shortcut st, nd, rd to column value - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

`Column A` has numbers from 1 - 5 and in column B i want to concatenate the number of `Column A` with the relevant nth term as indicated in the image below. Any help will be greatly appreciate!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Without using VBA, your best option would be the "`CHOOSE()`" function. 
Try something like this for any number > 0:

```
=IF(AND(MOD(ABS(A1),100)>10,MOD(ABS(A1),100)<14),"th",CHOOSE(MOD(ABS(A1),10)+1,"th","st","nd","rd","th","th","th","th","th","th"))
```

Comment: would this break on the numbers 111, 112, 113, 211, 212, 213, and so on?

Comment: @Marmiketin No it wouldn't. Using the MOD with AND means we can "trap" the case of ALL numbers like 11, 12, 13,, including 111, 112, 113, and add the suffix "th". All other numbers use the 10 suffix values inside CHOOSE.

The ABS function is used to handle negative numbers as well as positive numbers

Comment: so to return the number with the appended suffix you should use `=CONCAT(SQRT(A1^2),IF(AND(MOD(ABS(A1),100)>10,MOD(ABS(A1),100)<14),"th",CHOOSE(MOD(ABS(A1),10)+1,"th","st","nd","rd","th","th","th","th","th","th")))` where the `SQRT(A1^2)` removes negatives from numbers and combines it with the suffix your formula returns.

Comment: Actually I guess I could use the ABS(A1) instead of SQRT(A1^2) as they both do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a named "key" separately, much like the table you are showing, and then reference the key to replace any number with the desired output.

You can then indexmatch/vlookup the number, referencing the table, to find the output.

For ex:

```
=vlookup($A1,key,2,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use nested `IF` functions and `RIGHT` like this
`=IF(OR(RIGHT(H2,2)="11",RIGHT(H2,2)="12",RIGHT(H2,2)="13"),CONCAT(H2,"th"),IF(RIGHT(H2,1)="1",CONCAT(H2,"st"),IF(RIGHT(H2,1)="2",CONCAT(H2,"nd"),IF(RIGHT(H2,1)="3",CONCAT(H2,"rd"),CONCAT(H2,"th")))))`

Probably not the fastest performance wise